# Three-stage boost converter + Improvements

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice, boost

**EDIT**
As mentioned in the comments, a realistic load for me would be from 1 kΩ to 100 kΩ. I also was using damping resistors at each stage but it was pointed out to me that they are not needed, so here is the revised version.

**EDIT #2**
As @andyaka pointed out the MOSFET and the diodes must be able to handle high voltages and high currents. I chose the MOSFET with the highest breakdown voltage (850 V).
As for the diodes, I swapped the old diode for one that has a forward 60 A current instead of the old 20 A and a breakdown voltage of 1200 V. I also changed the load resistance to 10 kΩ. Graphs are updated.

**EDIT #3**
Here is a three stage boost converter that I simulated in LTSpice.

I am getting the high voltage output that I desire (1.3 kV). Before I proceed to the design phase, I would like to discuss a few things.

My questions are the following:

-Are there any obvious problems with the circuit?

-This is a single block of a larger system, if the next block of the system has a lower impedance, and I encounter a load regulation problem, is there some precautions I have to take for that?

-I would like to deliver a higher current (3-4 A) than what I have at the moment, how do I go about that?

-What topology would be recommended if I want to implement a feedback loop?

These are just questions of the top of my head...

I am basing myself off of this design:

[image]

According to the paper I am reading, my output should respect the following relation:

[image]

Given that Vin is 24 V and D is 0.71, I should be getting around 980 V.

Here is the circuit that I simulated. The values I chose follow what the paper says:

[image]

This is the output voltage I get:

[image]

I am seeing around 90 V at the output.

Here are the output voltages at each stage:

[image]

Here are the currents through each inductor:
[image]

This is the load current :
[image]
I have spent a lot of time changing different parameters, but nothing seems to work.

I would appreciate some plan/suggestion/ideas in order to fix my simulations and move to the design phase.

Comment: That is a fair point I will update the circuit

Comment: _”regardless of the the load impedance”_ Not happening. Define your max load.

Comment: I estimate that the load power just into the first stage is 376 watts and that doesn't seem feasible at all. Peak current in the MOSFET just for stage 1 is about 38 amps.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for fixing that?

Comment: A 1 kW boost circuit requires great care an attention so, start by explaining the load resistors on stage 1 and stage 2

Comment: The reason for these was to dampen the ringing, but I followed your advice and removed them @Andyaka

Comment: The MOSFET you have used is only rated for 800 volts. It's not my advice --> does the article show them? Please show your updated voltage graphs.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find a mosfet with higher voltage rating, and I already updated the graphs

Comment: What is the reverse voltage rating on the diodes?

Comment: I think 1kV, i think i checked that eatlier

Comment: *As mentioned in the comments a realistic load for me would be from 1k to 100k* <-- my comment was that the 1 kohm load in your schematic is likely to require great care and attention plus, I'll add that this topology is largely unsuitable for 1 kW. I'd say maybe 10 kohm load minimum.

Comment: okay I can work with 10k, i will adapt my design later

Comment: *This is a single block of a larger system* <-- are you saying that the 3 stage design may be followed by another block. If so why? Why not just cut to the chase and use a step-up  flyback transformer? What is ultimately your output power aim. I ask these questions because it's not clear where you are going and, I for one, cannot make an answer with these shifting goal-posts.

Comment: Why not just cut to the chase and use a step-up flyback transformer?
A: The reason for that is because I am not familiar with that circuit topology... 

 What is ultimately your output power aim?
A: Basically the 3 stages boost converter serves as a High Voltage supply. That DC voltage generated will be passed through a "buffer" or some sort of "pulse amplifier", pulses will be applied to that "buffer" using a pulse generatir the resulting output will be high voltage pulses applied to a load.
I hope the idea is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would like to deliver a higher current (3-4 A) than what I have at
> the moment, how do I go about that?*

If you want 3 or 4 amps at about 1 kV then you need to employ a design that will be able to handle this power (3 kW or 4 kW). A three stage booster (as you have in your question) won't cut the mustard and, now that you have specified your load current, neither will a flyback design.

My recommendation is to use a push-pull design with a centre tapped primary and secondary that can deliver the high voltage at the current you need: -

[image]

Image from [this](http://pws.npru.ac.th/thawatchait/data/files/High%20Power%20Step-Up%20Push-Pull%20DC-DC%20Converter%20with%20Parallel-.pdf) paper.

> *Are there any obvious problems with the circuit?*

It's a dead-end if you want the higher powers. Even if you didn't want the higher powers and, were happy with circa 100 watts out, I'd recommend a flyback design or a push-pull design (as per above).

Your voltage rating on the MOSFET needs to be **at-least** 20% higher than the actual output voltage AND, the MOSFETs in your diagram will fail because they are only rated at 800 volts.

> *What topology would be recommended if I want to implement a feedback
> loop?*

Any of the topologies (including a boost circuit) can be controlled by feedback however, the most tolerant is the push-pull design in my humble opinion. This is mainly because it's the input supply voltage and turns ratio that chiefly defines the output voltage even at low load currents.

Light loads on a booster or flyback will push the operating point inevitably into DCM (discontinuous conduction mode) and, you can easily destroy MOSFETs if you are not on top of your game.

> *if the next block of the system has a lower impedance, and I encounter
> a load regulation problem, is there some precautions I have to take
> for that*

The main precaution is cycle-by-cycle current limiting on the primary side in order to protect the output from excessive current due to unforeseen heavy loading.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will unpack everything in the days to come. I was wondering if i can get some resources where i can read on this circuit topology.

Comment: I don't have books or anything I can recommend @DimitarZhekov

Comment: No problem, I will do some research

Comment: @DimitarZhekov when you have a circuit idea come back and ask a new question. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).